# Entity Framework 5: Inheritance and Polymorphic Associations

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, orm, ado.net

Can someone tell me the best practice approach to mapping an inheritance model to Entity Framework 5?  Sometimes versions don't matter, but in this case it does because performance is key and EF5 has performance improvements.

Table per Type (TPT) and Table per Hierarchy (TPH) are not the only methods of doing it, but these are the methods I'm comparing.  I know that TPT has lower performance queries than TPH because of the complicated joins. I also know that with TPH, the table is denormalized which makes it hard to maintain in the long run.

I'm leaning towards TPT and performance tuning techniques.  Is this approach considered over engineering when TPH is much simpler to use?  Does the negative cost of maintenance outweigh the negative performance of TPT and the level of effort to do performance tuning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great article about it.  Basically, only use TPH for simple applications and consider other alternatives for more serious applications.  [Here is a great article about it](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/adam-anderson/2012/11/13/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-tpt-inheritance-mapping-in-entity-framework) and how to performance tune a TPT mapping.

Comment: Interesting. And the answer to "how-to-improve-the-performance-of-tpt-inheritance-mapping-in-entity-framework" ?  "Manual Mapping With Dapper" Couple of work items might be worth voting for: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1218 and https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/100

Answer (score 1):

Morteza Manavi wrote a series of blog posts about this a while ago:

1. [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 1 – Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).
2. [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx).
3. [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 3 – Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx).

At the end of the 3rd post, he gives this summary of the pros can cons of each modeling strategy and in which types of situations you would want to use one instead of another:

> Before we get into this discussion, I want to emphasize that there is no one single "best strategy fits all scenarios" exists. As you saw, each of the approaches have their own advantages and drawbacks. Here are some rules of thumb to identify the best strategy in a particular scenario:
>
> - If you don’t require polymorphic associations or queries, lean toward **TPC**—in other words, if you never or rarely query for BillingDetails and you have no class that has an association to BillingDetail base class. I recommend TPC (only) for the top level of your class hierarchy, where polymorphism isn’t usually required, and when modification of the base class in the future is unlikely.
> - If you do require polymorphic associations or queries, and subclasses declare relatively few properties (particularly if the main difference between subclasses is in their behavior), lean toward **TPH**. Your goal is to minimize the number of nullable columns and to convince yourself (and your DBA) that a denormalized schema won’t create problems in the long run.
> - If you do require polymorphic associations or queries, and subclasses declare many properties (subclasses differ mainly by the data they hold), lean toward **TPT**. Or, depending on the width and depth of your inheritance hierarchy and the possible cost of joins versus unions, use **TPC**.
>
> By default, choose TPH only for simple problems. For more complex cases (or when you’re overruled by a data modeler insisting on the importance of nullability constraints and normalization), you should consider the TPT strategy. But at that point, ask yourself whether it may not be better to remodel inheritance as delegation in the object model (delegation is a way of making composition as powerful for reuse as inheritance). Complex inheritance is often best avoided for all sorts of reasons unrelated to persistence or ORM. EF acts as a buffer between the domain and relational models, but that doesn’t mean you can ignore persistence concerns when designing your classes.